# Xorg Configuration for Unregistered Resolution

Tags: xorg, x11, monitors, resolution

I have a monitor with native resolution of `1600*900_60.00`, and the intel on board Gen3 Xeon video chipset `(i915)`.
when i do `$> xrandr` the `1600x900` resolution is not in the list. I tried to write an xorg configuration for monitor and I placed it on `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`. but i must mess some value in there up; that it ha no effect and doesn't change the resolution.
I am sure the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor` is being read at `$> startx` because if i put anything wrong like `()*!` at that file **X** won't start and produce an error.
The `cvt 1600 900` returns:

```
1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz 
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

also the `xrandr` produce:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1600x900_60.00�� (0xa5)  118.2MHz
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock   56.0KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934
```

And this is my `10-monitor.config` file:

```
Section "Device" 
Identifier  "Intel i915" 
  Option   "VGA1" #"VGA screen" 
  Driver      "intel"
EndSection 
Section "Monitor" 
  Identifier  "Primary Monitor" 
  Modeline    "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -Hsync +Vsync 
  Option      "PreferredMode" "1600x900" 
EndSection 
Section "Screen" 
     Identifier    "Screen0" 
     Device        "VGA1" 
     DefaultDepth  24 
     SubSection "Display" 
     Depth        24 
     Modes   "1600x900_60.00" 
EndSubSection 
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the --newmode option of xrandr to add the mode to X; then you can use the --addmode option of xrandr to add the mode to the output you are using. Then you should be able to select the mode using xrandr or a GUI mode selector.

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1600x900_60.00"
```

To change to the mode using xrandr:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

Unfortunately this solution must be repeated every time you restart (of course you could script it). I found this question looking for more information on how to write the permanent change in xorg.conf.

I plan to try the very simple xorg.conf answer in a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165030/unlisted-screen-resolution?s=1%7C2.2239)