# How to inform Xorg about a resolution I have already set?

Tags: xorg, xrandr, framebuffer, hdmi

I'm trying to get my Banana Pi Pro to switch between 1920x1080 and 1280x720 resolutions on an HDMI screen. Both resolutions work fine if I set them in [`uEnv.txt`](http://linux-sunxi.org/UEnv.txt):

```
 disp.screen0_output_mode=1280x720p60
 or
 disp.screen0_output_mode=1920x1080p60
```

Of course, changing bootloader scripts requires a reboot to take effect, which is undesirable. However, there's a way to change resolution without restart: `echo D:1280x720p-60>/sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode` effectively changes the resolution to 1280x720.

The problem is that Xorg is unavare of this change and keeps using the framebuffer as an 1920x1080 array, resulting in a "zebra" effect (similar to [this](http://www.virtuousgeek.org/bad%20stride.JPG) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0q2Z.jpg)). This effect can be partially fixed by setting a virtual resolution with `fbset`:

```
fbset -xres 1280 -yres 720 -vxres 1920 -vyres 1080
```

Now I get a clean image, however, only the 1280x720 top-left corner of the 1920x1080 virtual screen is physically displayed. Again, Xorg is unavare of the resolution change that took place, so no panning is enabled and any GUI controls spawned outside the top-left corner remain invisible.

I also tried to change the resolution via `xrandr` as described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224024/106927), but it seems that `xrandr` doesn't know how to change the resolution on my hardware, and refuses to set the new mode:

```
# xrandr --output default --mode 1280x720_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Is there a way to tell Xorg that the screen resolution have changed regardless of what errors `xrandr` reports, or without using `xrandr` at all? All it needs to do is to treat the framebuffer device as a 1280x720 array instead of 1920x1080.

I run Debian Wheezy (armhf port) with Openbox/LXDE if that matters.